# Blazor wasm, IIS, compression not for all files

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, blazor, http-compression

I have a web app created with blazor wasm standalone and published on IIS.
I use custom web.config for enable compression, as described here

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#standalone-deployment)

I noticed that not all files are compressed. Files under _content folder (css and js) are non compressed (there is no .br and .gz version).

Is there a way to enable compression also for this files?

Thank you

Comment: Did you enable static compression on iis? if not, please ensure that 'Enable static compression' is enabled.

Comment: @samwu yes, static compression is enabled

Comment: @andreat Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37836

and seems that files outside framerork folder are not compressed in Net6.
There is i way to compress them?
should i use IIS dynamic compression?
Thank you